# Can I end an "est-ce que" question with "est'?

Tags: questions

Is the following allowed?

> Où est-ce que ma chaise est?

I know other ways to say this, that I know to be correct, are "Où est ma chaise?" or "Ma chaise est où?".

But "Où est-ce que ma chaise est?" seems like it should be correct for the same reason that "Où est-ce que tu vas?" is correct. But I've never heard the former before.

If it isn't correct, why isn't it correct?

Comment: Getting a slight sense that it is indeed odd but possibly influenced by the prominence of "se trouver" in this construction. By comparison nothing strikes me as odd about "Comment est-ce qu'il est ?" except wordiness. Instincts may be off.

Comment: @guillau4: Thanks. I just corrected it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer: "Où est-ce que ma chaise est ?" is correct.

Long answer: "est-ce que" is used in order to keep the order between the subject and the verb.

For "Ma chaise est là." the following sentences are correct:

- "Où est ma chaise ?"
- "Où ma chaise est-elle ?"
- "Où est-ce que ma chaise est ?" (may sound weird)
- "Où est-ce qu'est ma chaise ?" (may sound weird)

Comment: So, "Où est-ce que ma chaise est?" does not sound odd to native speakers at all? I'm wondering why I never read or heard an "est-ce que" question that ends in "est", in any of the learning materials I've read or listened to.

Comment: For me it's totally correct. If you never read "est-ce que [...] est ?" is because it's a very particular situation. The french wikipedia page take a more common example : Est-ce que Sophie est arrivée ?
https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/est-ce_que

Comment: As Guillau4 say : "Où est-ce qu'est ma chaise?" is correct, and better. But for me, if "Où est-ce que ma chaise est ?" is strange, it still correct.

Comment: also don't forget "Où est ma chaise?". Another interesting fact, "Où est-ce que ma chaise est?" is a common idiom in Québec.

Comment: Going with idiomatic Québecois is a rabbit hole. Might as well call "Où c'est qu'elle est ma chaise?" idiomatic

Comment: Even better would be : "Où est-ce qu'elle est, ma chaise?" or "Ma chaise! Où est-ce qu'elle est?"

Comment: It is indeed accepted grammatically. French Canadians use phrases of this type often in spoken conversation, but rarely in written form. I think it's just because it seems less formal?

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but I would use a synonym to the verb être in order to sound less weird.. Like.. Où est-ce que ma chaise se trouve ?

Comment: Speaking as a native, I disagree with the statement that “Où est-ce que ma chaise est” is correct. It's comprehensible, but it sounds weird, I wouldn't say that, and I'd be surprised to hear a native say it.

Comment: Now it's opinion fight... I do not find any rule that goes one way or the other.

Comment: I don't know for French, Canadians and others but in Switzerland I'd also say `Elle est où ma chaise ?`

Comment: @Tim, `Elle est où ma chaise?` is, for me, like "argo" or popular formulation. Prefer other solutions.

Comment: Yes I wouldn't write it or say it in a French exam, but when speaking this comes very naturally to me even in a professional context.

Comment: As a native, I've never used "*Où est-ce que ma chaise est?*", but I often use "*Où est-ce que tu es?*" and "*Où est-ce qu'il/elle est?*". The first one really sounds weird to me

Comment: @WilliamPerron I'd say this seems like Québecois "*Tu veux tu [...]?*" which I find really disturbing as a French

Comment: Où est ma chaise? Definitely should be listed. That is the usual one.

Answer (score 14):

As a native I would say :

- Où est-ce qu'est ma chaise?
- Où est ma chaise?

I think you do not say `Où est-ce que ma chaise est?` or at least I never hear people using it.

Maybe because it is not a pronom, because `Où est-ce qu'elle est?` is used.

Maybe because there is nothing behind because `Où est-ce que ma chaise est passée?` is also used.

I do not know the rule behind it but it sounds very wrong to me.

Comment: assuming i'm not mistaken, none of the grammar books for French Learners give any rule that could create "Où est-ce qu'est ma chaise?" !

Comment: Maybe, but it does not seem wrong to me. Rules and books are nice, but they do not cover everything, especially slang.

Comment: I agree with Hawker65, rules in books are nice to learn how to speak correctly but they don't cover everything. They contain mostly general cases. Your question is hard to answer. My answer, to be honest, is opinion and experience based. This is why I said `as a native`. `Où est-ce que ma chaise est?` is apparently correct but not very used (in France Metropolitaine at least).

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu *où est-ce qu'est ma chaise ?* et corrigerait certainement mes enfants s'il le disaient. *Où est-ce qu'elle est ma chaise ?* est en revanche courant, comme pourrait aussi être *où est-ce qu'est cachée ma chaise ?*

Comment: While I wouldn't call “Où est-ce qu'est ma chaise” incorrect, I find it a little weird. It's one of those many redundant variants with a slightly jokey feel, like “Où qu'c'est qu'elle est ma chaise”.

Answer (score 6):

No, “*Où est-ce que ma chaise est?*” is not correct French. I don't have a grammatical explanation for it, just my native intuition. It sounds weird, I wouldn't expect a native speaker to say it. I think the weirdness comes from having the verb *être* at the end of the sentence, which apparently clashes with the fact that *être* always requires a complement (except in philosophy).

For yes/no questions, in informal spoken French, the verb-subject-complement syntax feels stilted and wouldn't be used, leaving a choice of “*est-ce que*” and using intonation only to convey that the sentence is a question. For questions that start with a question adverb, the adverb-verb-subject-complement syntax is sometimes acceptable in informal spoken French. You can ask “Où est ma chaise ?” in informal spoken French. In contrast “Où vas-tu ?” is ok but a bit formal, and “Quand viens-tu ?” is very formal. I don't have a grammatical explanation for this strange difference.

In informal spoken French, you can use the adverb-subject-verb order when the subject is a pronoun. Since informal spoken french lets you use a pronoun and put its antecedent after it in the same sentence, this doesn't limit what you can express this way.

> Où elle est ?   (formal: « Où est-elle ? »)
>   Où elle est ma chaise ?   (formal: « Où est ma chaise ? »)
>   Où il va ?   (formal: « Où va-t-il ? »)
>   Où il va ce type ?   (formal: « Où va cette personne ? »)

There's no straightforward “*est-ce que*” construction for “*où est ma chaise*”. Some of the informal variants of *est-ce que* do work, mostly with an extra pronoun.

> Où c'qu'elle est ma chaise ?
>   Où qu'elle est ma chaise ?
>   Où qu'c'est qu'elle est ma chaise ?
>   Ma chaise, où qu'elle est ?
>   Où est-ce qu'est ma chaise ?   (sounds a bit weird, but not wrong)
>   Où qu'est qu'c'est qu'est ma chaise ?

Comment: On entend souvent, quand quelqu’un recherche un objet de cette taille : « Ma chaise, elle est où ? » « Ma chaise, tu l'as vu ? | T'as pas vu ma chaise ? » et chez les anciens : « Ma chaise ? [bigre | zut | nom d'une pipe | … ] où est-elle passée ? » et aussi « Ma chaise, ousse qu'elle est ? » avec le *est* final.

Answer (score 0):

"Ma chaise est où?" is not <strike>correct</strike> **formal**. If you want to ask a question, you need to inverse the verb and the noun : "Où est ma chaise?", like you said.

You can ask questions without the question mark, these are called "Phrase interrogative passive (ou indirecte)" or something really close to that. For example : "J'aimerais savoir où se trouve ma chaise." is a question, "without a question".

If you want more advice regarding "est-ce que", you can follow [this link.](http://grammaire.reverso.net/3_1_27_est-ce_que.shtml)

"Où est-ce que tu vas?" and "Où est-ce que ma chaise est?" are both incorrect. In a direct interrogation sentence, as I said earlier, verb and noun need to be reversed. It is not the case here, as "tu" comes before "vas" and "ma chaise" comes before "est".

We could try to flip this direct interrogation to an indirect interrogation, but in this case, as pointed in the link I... linked.. earlier, you cannot use "est-ce que" in an indirect interrogation.

The correct syntax is therefore : "Où est ma chaise" and "Où vas-tu?".

Obviously, this is the formal grammar, but in everyday's life we use pretty much all of the formulations given in the answer.

Comment: "Ma chaise est où?" is correct informal spoken French. “Où est-ce que tu vas?” is correct spoken or written French. “Où vas-tu?” is one correct (formal) way to phrase the question but it is not the only one.

Comment: I agree my first sentence might be confusing, I wrote the last sentence of my answer to specify I was speaking of a formal context. I would also like to know why do you think "Où est-ce que tu vas" is formal. I might be wrong, but I've had pretty extensive french classes at university.

Answer (score 0):

> Où est ma chaise?
>   Où se trouve ma chaise?
>   Où est-ce que ma chaise se trouve?

Those are the possibilities I'd go for. Maybe `Où est-ce qu'est ma chaise` might be right, but I can't imagine a native French speaking person say this.